# saving CSV with UTF-16BE encoding in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, unicode, encoding

I am trying to write a CSV file with a character encoding set to UTF-16BE from a MySQL database encoded in UTF-8.

My code is:

```
$f = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
$firstLineKeys = false;

// UTF-16BE BOM
fwrite($f, chr(254) . chr(255));

foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $lineEncoded = [];

    foreach ($line as $key => $value) 
    {
        $key = mb_convert_encoding($key, 'UTF-16BE', "auto");
        $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-16BE', "auto");
        $lineEncoded[$key] = $value;
    }

    if (empty($firstLineKeys))
    {
        $firstLineKeys = array_keys($lineEncoded);

        fputcsv($f, $firstLineKeys);

        $firstLineKeys = array_flip($firstLineKeys);
    }

    fputcsv($f, array_merge($firstLineKeys, $lineEncoded));
}

fclose($f);
```

When I open the file in OpenOffice it try's to import it with a character set of Unicode but the fields are a mess... when I switch the import character set to UTF-8 it looks correct.

Any help would be apprecated thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$key = mb_convert_encoding($key, 'UTF-16BE', "auto");
```

(Are you sure you want BE? It's a pretty rarely-used encoding. Windows “Unicode” is UTF-16LE.)

I would avoid using `"auto"` as the from_encoding. It's an unreliable bodge that will often produce the wrong results especially on short strings. As the input is apparently UTF-8 you should state that explicitly instead.

```
fputcsv($f, array_merge($firstLineKeys, $lineEncoded));
```

Unfortunately `fputcsv` can't write to a UTF-16-encoded file. It uses single-byte ASCII commas/quotes/newlines so it only works for encodings that are ASCII supersets. So if you wanted to use it you would have to write the whole file as UTF-8, and then transcode the whole file to UTF-16.

You might want to consider a different (or your own) CSV writer instead; as well as being annoying to use for non-ASCII encodings, `fputcsv` also doesn't comply with the RFC standard for CSV files, so you can easily generate files most CSV-consuming software can't load properly.

PHP's in-built CSV functions are essentially a complete waste of everyone's time.

Comment: How does it not conform to the standards?

Comment: As long as you use `fputcsv($handle, $array, ',', '"', "\0")` it should escape everything properly (after reading the linked bug). `fgetcsv` seems to be a different story though