# Convert encoding of file data using stream_filter_append

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to convert a file I am creating to UTF-16LE during the creation process using stream_filter_append(). But, I'm just getting garbled data from the output. Example code below

```
    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($fp, chr(255) . chr(254));
    $rows = array(array('Состав Gerber', 'Секреты производства'), array('Полезные аксессуары', 'Инструменты'));
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    stream_filter_append($fp, 'convert.iconv.UTF-8/UTF-16LE', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);
    fclose($fp);
```

I can't use iconv on the data before passing it through fputcsv, because fputcsv doesn't handle UTF-16. [saving CSV with UTF-16BE encoding in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229207/saving-csv-with-utf-16be-encoding-in-php)

I know I have the option to create the file, then read and convert it. Or even create a custom fputcsv to handle UTF-16. But I was wondering if this would be possible during the initial file creation process using stream_filter_append().

Comment: I can't believe how much testing I did before I spotted this, but why would you think that appending the filter to the stream *after* writing the data would affect the data that you had already written? Move it to the line after you write the BOM.

Comment: Yep that was it, incorrect placement of stream_filter_append(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by @Sammitch in the comments of the question. He realized the placement of stream_filter_append() was incorrectly used after writing the data. It should be used before writing. A correct example is below.

```
$fp = fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($fp, chr(255) . chr(254));
stream_filter_append($fp, 'convert.iconv.UTF-8/UTF-16LE', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);
$rows = array(array('Состав Gerber', 'Секреты производства'), array('Полезные аксессуары', 'Инструменты'));
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
}
fclose($fp);
```